# Hi, while I was trying to run this code this mensage came up ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.lemmatizer'

Tags: python

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
from spacy.lemmatizer import Lemmatizer
from spacy.lang.en import LEMMA_INDEX, LEMMA_EXC, LEMMA_RULES
lemmatizer = Lemmatizer(LEMMA_INDEX, LEMMA_EXC, LEMMA_RULES)
lemmattizer('chunkles', 'NOUN')
```

Can anyone help me? I'm using Version 3 of python

Comment: did you install the module? Try `pip install spacy`

Comment: @dieserniko If they didn't, they would have gotten an error on `import spacy`.

Comment: It looks like the API for `lemmatizer` has changed in Spacy 3 – https://spacy.io/api/lemmatizer ... Maybe install an older version of Spacy or fix that code to work with the 3.x API.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The official document shows that after spacy 3.0, the lemmatizer has become a standalone pipeline component. Therefore, you should install the spacy whose version is smaller than 3.0. The link is as follow: https://spacy.io/api/lemmatizer

Answer (score 0):

try:
doc = nlp('chuckles')
doc[0].lemma_

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).